# QGIS: Legend patches do not honor opacity

Tags: qgis, legend, transparency-opacity

**Background:**

At 3.22.3 I have a slope raster (32-bit floating point, single-band tif) derived from a DTM. I display this using a discrete interpolation, with three value ranges: 0-20, 20-40, and 40-90 degrees. These three ranges are symbolized with blue, green, and red, respectively.  *However*, I require that the blue color be displayed with 25% opacity, as shown in the screenshot below.  Green and red have opacity = 100%.

[image]

**Problem:**

When displayed in a Print Layout, the blue color with the 25% opacity displays correctly in both the map and in the Legend Properties, screenshot below.

But note that the map legend patch does not honor the 25% opacity.  Instead, a solid color is displayed.

There is a [Github bug report with a similar problem](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31949), but it was closed without resolution two years ago.

There is also a [SE GIS post from 4 years ago](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225522/opacity-transparency-in-raster-legend-qgis), again without resolution.

[image]

**Question:**

How to force legend patches to honor opacity settings?

Comment: Just tried, I reproduced it, I comment the QGIS issue with a GIF and ask to reopen.

Comment: I'm glad to see that its not just me, and appears to be a bug!

Comment: New issue about this bug : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47612